# I want to get keys names from hash which has same values in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
{"Amar"=>20,"Benton"=>14,"John"=>32,"Sunny"=>28,"Edward"=>19,"Leon"=>12,"Ram"=>19,"David"=>28}
```

the above hash has name and age ,i want to get the names which has same age in ruby

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: did you even search? atleast you could share the expected output.

Comment: It is more like an algorithm question, and seems no built-in methods for such a corner algorithm question.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
hash = {"name1"=>12, "name2"=>13, "name3"=>12}

groups = {}
hash.each do |k, v|
  groups[v] = groups[v] || []
  groups[v].push(k)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create a hash with ages as the key and an array of names as the values:

```
names = {"Amar"=>20,
         "Benton"=>14,
         "John"=>32,
         "Sunny"=>28,
         "Edward"=>19,
         "Leon"=>12,
         "Ram"=>19,
         "David"=>28}

ages = {}
names.each do |key, value|
  ages[value] ||= []
  ages[value] << key
end

puts ages
#=> {20=>["Amar"], 14=>["Benton"], 32=>["John"], 28=>["Sunny", "David"], 19=>["Edward", "Ram"], 12=>["Leon"]}
```

Note that if you want to get all the people who are 19 years old, you can just use `ages[19]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
hash = {"Amar"=>20,"Benton"=>14,"John"=>32,"Sunny"=>28,"Edward"=>19,"Leon"=>12,"Ram"=>19,"David"=>28}

hash.keys.group_by { |k| hash[k] }.values.select { |g| g.size > 1 }
# => [["Sunny", "David"], ["Edward", "Ram"]]
```

Sunny and David have the same age, and so do Edward and Ram.

Answer (score 1):

For your hash

```
 names_hash = {"Amar"=>20,"Benton"=>14,
  "John"=>32,"Sunny"=>28,
  "Edward"=>19,"Leon"=>12,
  "Ram"=>19,"David"=>28}
```

You can always define a method which gives the desired names for an age

```
def names_for_age(age, hash = {})
  hash.inject({}) do |container, (k,v)|
    container[v] ||= []
    container[v] << k
    container
  end[age]
end
```

So, now you can get the names as

```
names_for_age(10, names_hash)
```